# Django render Dictionary

Tags: python, django

Why cant i acsess the dict that i am making here:

```
def kalkuler(request):

    fotlister = Produkt.objects.filter(under_kategori__navn__iexact="lister")
    kalkuler = ProduktKalkureing.objects.all()

    beregning = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        omkrets = request.POST['omkrets']
        print(omkrets)
        for i in kalkuler:
            kalk = math.ceil((int(omkrets)/i.lengde)*1000)

            add = ({'produkt_tittel': i.produkt.produkt_tittel,
                    'produkt_bilde': i.produkt.produkt_bilde,
                    'produkt_info': i.produkt.produkt_info,
                    'produkt_link': i.produkt.produkt_link,
                    'pris_heltall': i.produkt.pris_heltall,
                    'antall_kalk': kalk,
                    'total_kost': kalk * i.produkt.pris_heltall
                    })

            beregning.update(add)

    print(beregning)

    context = {'kalkuler': kalkuler, 'beregning': beregning}

    return render(request, 'frontend/kalkuler/fotlist_kalkuler.html', context)
```

With the standard django code?

```
{% for b in beregning %}
   {{b.produkt_bilde}}
{% endfor %}
```

Also when i make the dictionary it only adds the last value. How do i make it so it adds every value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you seem to achieve, you need a `list` instead of a `dict`

```py
def kalkuler(request):
    ...
    beregning = []
    ...
        beregning.append(add)
    ...
```